# Como hacer expresion regular para equivalencia a la eñe

Tags: java, regex

quedria hacer una expresion regular para que en un replaceAll(), cambie las eñe, acentos y demas que se forman simbolos raros al pasarlos por Get. 
Por ejemplo el simbolo raro es %FA, entonces al encontrar equivalencias lo cambie por la ñ. 
Yo probe con la expresion regular [%FA] pero no esta bien definida por lo visto.

Y no es problema de codificacion UTF-8 y demas , porque por post va todo perfectamente, tengo todo en UTF-8, archivos Java, XML, base de datos, Tomcat.

Agradezco mucho la ayuda,

Saludos

---

He probado con los das formas que me habeis propuesto(replaceAll y URLDecoder.decode) y sigue sin funcionar. De hecho la de URLDecoder.decode me funciona en la misma aplicación pero ejecutandolo en otro servidor web, me explico. Si utilizo glassfish me funciona, y si lo utilizo en Tomcat es cuando funciona mal. He de decir que en ambos servidores web tengo configurado en los jsp como ISO-8859-1 y en el web.xml esta en UTF-8, no me pregunteis porque pero si lo pongo todo emparejado falla. Y ademas en glassfish no me hizo falta tocar nada, pero en Tomcat si el archivo server.xml indicando que el metodo de codificación iba a ser UTF-8 y lo mismo en el archivo de Catalina, y en Tomcar va todo bien pasado por Post pero el unico arhchivo que pasa por Get le ocurre esto. Y creedme he probado con todo en cuanto a que Tomcat-los jsp-web.xml tengan los mismos metodos de codificacion y la unica fomra de que funcione casi todo bien es como lo está ahora. De nuevo gracias por ayudarme con esto. Es que necesito entregarlo con Tomcat, porque es para el proyecto final de ciclo y debemos presentarlo así.
Gracias!

---

lo he solucionado y a funcionado durante un rato, era problema de la base de datos. Las tablas las tenia en UTF8, pero la base de datos en latin1. Cambie todos los archivos de Java a UTF8, y ha estado funcionando durante un rato.

En Tomcat con todo utf-8 modificado en la base de datos, en todo momento guarda la informacion de las eñes con simbolos raros como  Ã±Ã±Ã±Ã±Ã±Ã±Ã He probado a la variable en la servlet que va guardar los datos en la base de datos a utilizar  String Nombre = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(nombre, "UTF-8"); pero ni con esas.

Tengo bien localizado el problema, me explico, tengo dos aplicaciones una web entorno cliente con la misma configuracion que la otra que es la tipica aplicacion para el administrador(administrar las tablas, los usuarios), pues en esta última aplicacion es donde falla. Si desde el entorno cliente se guarda una imagen los datos se quedan bien guardados en la base de datos y despues se muestran bien en el el entorno del administrador. Si modifico ó inserto una nueva imagen desde el entorno administrador ahi es donde falla. Para insertar o modificar la magen utilizo un formulario en jsp, que le pasa la info a una servlet que guardara los datos en la base de datos. Ahi he probado a hacer un String Nombre = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(nombre, "UTF-8");(siendo nombre la variable recogida del jsp) y a diferencia del entorno cliente que este metodo lo soluciona en este caso no funciona. Tengo el mapeado en web.xml con la codificacion en UTF-8 al igual que en el entorno cliente. 
Por eso es extraño como estando exactamente igual en una aplicacion funciona y en otra no.

No se si os ocurriran más ideas?, me hariais un gran favor

Muchas gracias de antemano :)

Comment: nombreDeCadena = nombreDeCadena.replaceAll("%FA", "ñ") no te funciona? De todas maneras tengo que decirte que no es una buena práctica utilizara ñ en tu url (y casi en ningún sitio) ya que es un caracter que solo tenemos los hispano hablantes

Answer (score 2):

## Antes de nada...

Tienes un par de conceptos erróneos:

1. No se trata de "símbolos raros", sino de un estándar acerca de qué caracteres están permitidos como parte de una URL, y cómo representar los que no están permitidos. Está descrito en el [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) en el epígrafe "Percent-Encoding". Por tanto la forma de tratar con estas URLs no es mediante expresiones regulares ni sustituciones ad-hoc, sino mediante métodos (como los proporcionados por [`java.net.URLDecoder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html)) que sepan cómo decodificar este formato.
2. Dices que no está relacionado con el *encoding*, pero sí lo está de forma inderecta, ya que el resultado de decodificar una URL "percent-encoded", será en general una secuencia de bytes y qué caracteres son los representados en esa secuencia de bytes depende de la elección de un *encoding* concreto.

Por resumir, cada vez que aparece un `%` formando parte de una URL, los dos caracteres siguientes han de ser, o bien dígitos(`0` a `9`) o bien una letra de la `A` a la `F`. Los dos juntos dan el valor de un byte expresado en hexadecimal.

Así, en tu ejemplo, dices que la ñ te aparece como `%FA`. En realidad esto significa que la `ñ` ha sido codificada como un byte de valor hexadecimal `FA` (que en decimal sería 250), y ese byte, al no ser un carácter válido en una URL, ha sido recodificado a su vez como la secuencia de caracteres `%FA`.

Pero el primer paso, la conversión de `ñ` en un byte concreto, ha requerido de un *encoding*. No sabemos cuál ha sido, aunque cabe hacer algunas hipótesis. Si el resultado ha sido un solo byte, es porque no hemos usado UTF-8. Usando UTF-8 cualquier caracter no-ascii ocupa varios bytes (lo que significa que aparecería como una secuencia de varios `%XX%XX` en la URL). En concreto, en UTF-8 la `ñ` se representa mediante dos bytes de valores (hexadecimales) `C3` y `B1`, por lo que en la URL se vería así: `%C3%B1`.

Tu ejemplo usa un *encoding* en el que la `ñ` es un solo byte. Los ecodings de un solo byte más frecuentemente usados en español son: [ISO-8859-1](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) (también llamado Latin1), Windows [CP-1252](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) (que es muy similar a Latin1 y en concreto tiene el mismo código para la `ñ` y las vocales acentuadas, diferenciándose sólo en otros símbolos poco comunes) y MS-DOS [CP-850](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%A1gina_de_c%C3%B3digos_850). Si miras las tablas de códigos de estos *encodings*, vemos que ninguno de ellos tiene una `ñ` en su código `FA`

Hasta donde he podido averiguar, **ningún** encoding tiene ese código para la eñe (he hecho un script python que prueba todos los encodings posibles) por lo que sospecho que te has equivocado y que era en realidad `%F1`, que, ese sí, sería el código de la `ñ` en Latin1.

## La solución

La solución, como dije, pasa por usar `java.net.URLDecoder` y no expresiones regulares o sustituciones de cadenas. Pero también requiere que sepas el *encoding* utilizado para convertir los caracteres no-ascii en bytes, pues es necesario para poder reconstruir los caracteres originales.

Por ejemplo, supongamos que tengo la siguiente URL:

```
http://mi.sitio.com/query?txt=Esto%20contiene%20e%F1es%20y%20%E1%20%E9%20acentos
```

y que sabemos que se ha usado el *encoding* `latin1` (otro nombre de `ISO-8859-1`) para su codificación. Entonces el siguiente ejemplo en java te permitirá reconstruir el texto:

```
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String url="http://mi.sitio.com/query?txt=Esto%20contiene%20e%F1es%20y%20%E1%20%E9%20acentos";
        String result = URLDecoder.decode(url, "latin1");
        System.out.println(result);     
    }
}
```

Al ejecutar el programa anterior, en consola saldrá:

```
http://mi.sitio.com/query?txt=Esto contiene eñes y á é acentos
```

Comment: para completar tu respuesta, la W3C encargada de los estandares de la Web [Explica mas en detalle  sobre la codificacion](https://www.w3.org/International/O-URL-code.html), puedes ver la [lista de encoding utf-8](https://www.utf8-chartable.de)